# Create an array of pointers of a superclass to heap allocate inheritted classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

Basically, I want to work with an array of pointers of a superclass and use them for subclasses.

I have a code that manipulates geometric forms. It's a "geometric forms" superclass, consisting of virtual methods and static ints.

Later in the code, I create inherited classes (circles, squares..), complementing the application.

I want to create an array of "geometric forms" pointer and pass the `i`'th item (index based on static attribute) to a specific sub-function, based on a `switch` case, responsible for methods for that geometric figure, with that `i`'th pointer.

Example: I want to work with squares, so I pass a `menuSquares(geometricFroms *array[foo::getStatic()]){}`...

Inside that function, I want to do:

```cpp
ptrPassed = new Circle();
```

How can I do that?

I tried using a generic `int` pointer instead of a superclass type:

```cpp
Class GeomFig {};

Class Circle : public GeomFig
{};

int main(){

    GeomFig *arrayPtrs[100];

    // selection of which shape the user wants to use
    // ...

    menuSquares(arrayPtrs[GeomFig::getStatic()]) {}...

}

// code def
menuSquares(GeomFig* &geomPtr)
{
    geomPtr = new Circle();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `menuSquares()` is taking its `GeomFig*` parameter **by value**, so the parameter is local to `menuSquares()` only and anything assigned to it inside of `menuSquares()` will not be seen by the caller.

If you want the caller to see the new pointer value, you need to pass the pointer **by reference** instead:

```cpp
void menuSquares(GeomFig* &geomPtr)
{
    geomPtr = new Circle();
}
```

Otherwise, have `menuSquares()` return the desired pointer in its return value instead of using an output parameter:

```cpp
GeomFig* menuSquares()
{
    return new Circle();
}

...

arrayPtrs[GeomFig::getStatic()] = menuSquares();
```

Comment: I was doing this, forgot to write in the github code itself. It's not about the way the function gets the ptr, its about calling a constructor on it

Comment: @DiogoNeiss what about it? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to call the heap allocate a inherited class on a generic superclass pointer

Comment: @DiogoNeiss I don't understand what you are trying to ask. But it is certainly allowed to construct a derived class and assign the object to a base class pointer